# Worded Conditional Probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

A student has studied only 20% of the material for a module that is examined via
multiple choice questions.

Given that a question covers the material he has studied, the student will definitely
answer correctly.

Given that a question covers material that he has not studied, he picks an answer at
random.

You can assume that a question either covers material he has studied, or not.

We give the student one multiple choice question with four choices and only 1 right
answer.

Q1) given that the student answered correctly, what is the probability he picked the answer at random

My approach:

Let A=picked answer at Random

B=picked answer correctly

P(A|B)= $  \frac {P \left( A \bigcap B \right)}{P\left ( B \right )}$

$P\left ( B \right )$=1/4

however i am unable to find out the numerator as I cant figure out $P(A)$

Comment: Your denominator should be the sum of the probabilities that the student answered correctly since he had studied the appropriate material and that the student answered correctly by guessing the correct answer despite not studying the appropriate material.  Your numerator should be the latter term.

Comment: The problem statement fails to make it clear that the questions target a uniformly random item of the material (or you didn't copy it in full here). However, under the additional assumption that this is the case, you will at some point want to use the $20\,\%$ figure.

Answer (score 1):

$P$(Correct Answer | Picked the answer at random) = $1/4$ 
$P$(Correct Answer | Picked the answer intelligently) = $1$

There are only two possibilities: Either the student Picked the answer at random, or intelligently. They can pick the answer intelligently only if it comes from that 20% syllabus that they studied. Assuming that the probability of question coming from the syllabus is uniform over the syllabus, the probability that they picked the answer intelligently is 20%, i.e. $20/100=1/5$ 
$P$(Picked the answer at random) = $4/5$ 
$P$(Picked the answer intelligently) = $1/5$

$P$(Correct Answer) = $(1/4\times4/5) + (1\times1/5)$ = $2/5$

P(Picked the answer at random | Correct Answer) 
= $\dfrac{P(\text{Correct Answer | Picked the answer at random}) * P(\text{Picked the answer at random}) }{ P(\text{Correct Answer}) }$ 
= $\dfrac{(1/4 \times 4/5)}{(2/5)}$ = $1/2$

Comment: how did you get P(picked the answer at random ) to be 4/5 ?

Comment: the student has only studied 20% of the material. Hence only 1/5 probability that they Picked the answer intelligently. Rest of the probability (4/5) is that they picked the answer as random

Comment: @RoboJumble is that clear?

Comment: how does 80% not studied = to the probability of Random

Comment: @RoboJumble The question states that 
*"Given that a question covers material that he has not studied, he picks an answer at random."*

Comment: Yes that’s only on the condition .

Comment: @RoboJumble  There are only two possibilities: a question covers the material he has studied; or it does not. First has probability 20%, the latter has 80%. In first case always the student will pick  answer intelligently; in second case the student will always pick answer randomly.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ denote the event that the student got the question right because it was on material that he studied.

Let $B$ denote the event that the student got the question right.

Per [Bayes Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem), you have that

$$p(A|B) \times p(B) = p(A,B) \implies p(A|B) = \frac{p(A,B)}{p(B)}$$

$$= \frac{(.2) \times (1.0)}{[ ~(.2) \times (1.0) ~] ~+~ 
[ ~(0.8) \times (0.25) ~]}$$

$$= \frac{.2}{.2 + .2} = \frac{1}{2}.$$

Notice that your computation of $p(B)$ is wrong, and should in fact be $(0.4).$